# Given $\lceil x−1 \rceil$, how can I compute $\lfloor x \rfloor$ without using $modulo$?

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

I have $\lceil x \rceil = -\lfloor -x \rfloor$, but I can't figure out how to rely on this in order to get $\lfloor x \rfloor$ from $\lceil x−1 \rceil$.

For the record, I am only interested in non-negative real values.

I wish to avoid the use of $modulo$, $abs$, $round$ and $if$.

The motivation behind this question is as follows:

$$x-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\arctan(\tan(\pi(x-\frac{1}{2})))}{\pi}=\lceil x-1 \rceil$$

How do I "manipulate" the value of $x$ in order to get $\lfloor x \rfloor$ instead of $\lceil x-1 \rceil$?

**UPDATE:**

I also have this if it helps:

$$x+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\arctan(\tan(\pi(-x-\frac{1}{2})))}{\pi}=\lceil x \rceil$$

Comment: If $x\in\mathbb N$, $\lceil x-1 \rceil = x-1 = \lfloor x \rfloor - 1$, else $\lceil x-1\rceil = \lfloor x \rfloor$. Without additional information, this is impossible. ($\pm0$)

Comment: What about $\lceil{x-1\rceil}=\lceil{x\rceil}-1$?

Answer (score 1):

You know that $\lfloor x\rfloor=-\lceil-x\rceil$, so if you replace $x$ by $-x$ and multiply the equation by $-1$, you get
$$x-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\arctan(\tan(\pi(x-\frac{1}{2})))}{\pi}=-\lceil -x \rceil=\lfloor x\rfloor$$

Comment: Can you please see updated question, as to the motivation behind it?

Comment: No it doesn't. Take a look at your proposed function. It is identical to the first one in my question, which yields $\lceil x-1 \rceil$.

Comment: @barakmanos Right. I forgot $x$ can't be an integer, then it's even true that $\lceil x-1\rceil=\lfloor x\rfloor$ and you don't have to derive it from the updated version like I did. Is it clear how I did it?

Comment: Yes it is. But it doesn't provide an answer to my question, unless I use $if$ inside the function.

Comment: @barakmanos Well, graphing it [here] alongside a floor function seems to be the exact same function as a result. [here]=https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yuousd7vdl

Comment: @ConorO'Brien: What this graph doesn't tell you (because it's impossible to notice with floor-like functions), is that they are not the same at some of the end points. In particular, for positive integers, the other function gives the wrong result. For example, $f(2)=1\neq2=\lfloor2\rfloor$.

Comment: @Barak I see.... I'd suggest a piecewise equation, but that's an $if$ thing.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien: Thanks. As you mentioned yourself - *piecewise* is equivalent to *if*. So up until now I have not received an appropriate answer to that (though I did get down-voted at some point by someone who apparently thought that the question wasn't good enough for some reason).

Answer (score 0):

If $x\in\mathbb N$, $\lceil x-1 \rceil = x-1 = \lfloor x \rfloor - 1$, else $\lceil x-1\rceil = \lfloor x \rfloor$. Without additional information, this is impossible.

Comment: Thanks @AlexR, but what do you mean by "additional information"? Also, I wish to avoid the use of $modulo$, $abs$, $round$ and $if$ (updated the question accordingly).

Comment: @barakmanos This means if $\lceil x-1 \rceil$ is the only piece of information you have, you _can't_ figure out $\lfloor x \rfloor$. You need the information if $x\in\mathbb N$ in some form or another. For example $(x-\lceil x-1\rceil > 0)$ (as a boolean) would suffice. If it is false, $x\in\mathbb N$, else $x\notin\mathbb N$. And from there you can use the two formulas given.